# How to access the same service provider for different tenant users in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 for my production server, and I want to divide my users into two groups. I am using the SAML protocol with my service provider. How can the SAML application be configured as a service provider for two tenants in WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tick "SaaS Application" option in SP, it will be available for all tenants.

Comment: Thanks alot M.Bhathiya , its works Well , but i really want to grouping my users in order to provide different authentication methods (steps) per group ! there is any help ?